# Concatenate multiple zlib compressed data streams into a single stream efficiently

Tags: python, zlib

If I have several binary strings with compressed zlib data, is there a way to *efficiently* combine them into a single compressed string without decompressing everything?

Example of what I have to do now:

```
c1 = zlib.compress("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. ")
c2 = zlib.compress("We ride at dawn! ")
c = zlib.compress(zlib.decompress(c1)+zlib.decompress(c2)) # Warning: Inefficient!

d1 = zlib.decompress(c1)
d2 = zlib.decompress(c2)
d = zlib.decompress(c)

assert d1+d2 == d # This will pass!
```

Example of what I want:

```
c1 = zlib.compress("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. ")
c2 = zlib.compress("We ride at dawn! ")
c = magic_zlib_add(c1+c2) # Magical method of combining compressed streams

d1 = zlib.decompress(c1)
d2 = zlib.decompress(c2)
d = zlib.decompress(c)

assert d1+d2 == d # This should pass!
```

I don't know too much about zlib and the DEFLATE algorithm, so this may be entirely impossible from a theoretical point of view. Also, I must use use zlib; so I can't wrap zlib and come up with my own protocol that transparently handles concatenated streams.

NOTE: I don't really mind if the solution is not trivial in Python. I'm willing to write some C code and use ctypes in Python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you don't mind venturing into C, you can start by looking at the code for *[gzjoin](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/gzjoin.c)*.

Note, the *gzjoin* code has to decompress to find the parts that have to change when merged, but it doesn't have to recompress.  That's not too bad because decompression is typically faster than compression.

Comment: This wasn't as simple as I had hoped, but it is definitely more efficient that what I was doing before. Thanks.

Comment: Specifically answering the question, you cannot combine two deflate streams without decompressing the first one, as gzjoin does.  Though if you are in control of creating the first deflate stream, it can be specially prepared to append to it without decompressing.

Comment: OMG, A comment from @MarkAdler about compression.  That is like hearing from the Dalai Lama about finding inner peace.  Can you expand on your mention about controlling the first deflate stream?  We are trying to do something similar with zlib-streams using Z_SYNC_FULL to accomplish something along these lines.

Comment: You can complete the deflation with `Z_SYNC_FLUSH` (or `Z_FULL_FLUSH` -- doesn't matter in this case), making sure that you get all of the compressed data after that (`strm.avail_out != 0`), and then follow that with a `Z_FINISH`.  Then you can strip the last two bytes of the stream and directly concatenate another deflate stream to that.

Comment: To find inner peace, accept yourself as you are, and accept others as they are.

Comment: @MarkAdler Thanks, you pointed us in the right direction. I'm working with meawoppl on a parallelized PNG compressor. We weren't able to concatenate two streams using the method you suggested, but we were able to get it to work this way: For the first stream, call deflate with a Z_SYNC_FLUSH. For each subsequent stream, call deflate with Z_SYNC_FLUSH, strip the *first* two bytes, and concatenate, also collecting the adler32 value and uncompressed length. Then for the last stream, deflate with a Z_FINISH, strip off the 4 byte checksum, and replace it with adler32_combine() of all the checksums.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to gzjoin which requires decompression of the first deflate stream, you can take a look at [gzlog.h](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/gzlog.h) and [gzlog.c](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/gzlog.c), which efficiently appends short strings to a gzip file without having to decompress the deflate stream each time.  (It can be easily modified to operate on zlib-wrapped deflate data instead of gzip-wrapped deflate data.)  You would use this approach if you are in control of the creation of the first deflate stream.  If you are not creating the first deflate stream, then you would have to use the approach of gzjoin which requires decompression.

None of the approaches require recompression.

Comment: It's good to know that the writer of zlib is answering the question. :D

I will look into these. Thanks for your contribution to the free software world!

Comment: You said that the `gzjoin` technique only needs to decompress the first stream.  However, the code seems to treat all streams the same (and call `inflate()` on all of them).  Am I misreading it?

Also, you said that if the first stream is specially-constructed, no decompression is necessary.  Is it possible to specially-construct a stream with zero bytes of original input data, then use that as the first stream every time?

Comment: You can combine two deflate streams by decoding only the first one.  However gzip streams don't always end at the end of the bytes, so gzjoin.c decodes the last one as well in order to make sure it knows where the deflate data really ends to correctly locate the crc and length.

Comment: The five bytes 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff is a zero-length stored block that ends on a byte boundary.  So you can concatenate any deflate stream to that.  However I am not clear on how that is useful for you.

Comment: Let's say I have two 10MB deflate streams that I want to concatenate.  You said we only need to decompress the first stream to concatenate them.  Can we pretend we're concatenating three streams -- the special zero-length stream, followed by the two 10MB streams?  This way we only have to decompress the zero-length stream and not the first 10MB stream.  Am I misunderstanding something?  (BTW, thanks for taking the time to answer!)

Comment: You don't need to decompress the zero-length stream since you constructed it.  You can construct it to be byte-aligned without the last bit set, so it can simply be prepended.  You can always prepend a deflate stream with `0x00 0x00 0x00 0xff 0xff`.  (An empty stored block.)   Or `0x02 0x08 0x20 0x80 0x00`.  (Four empty fixed-code blocks.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm just turning [@zorlak's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744692/concatenate-multiple-zlib-compressed-data-streams-into-a-single-stream-efficient#comment52065643_14744792) into an answer and adding some code so I can find it later.

> For the first stream, call `deflate()` with a `Z_SYNC_FLUSH`. For each subsequent stream, call `deflate()` with `Z_SYNC_FLUSH`, strip the first two bytes, and concatenate, also collecting the adler32 value and uncompressed length. Then for the last stream, [call] `deflate()` with a `Z_FINISH`, strip off the 4 byte checksum, and replace it with `adler32_combine()` of all the checksums.

If you can control the initial compression of your streams, you can store the length of the uncompressed data, its Adler-32 checksum, and the compressed data somewhere. Later you can then concatenate the individual streams in an arbitrary order.

Note that I am not sure if the individual streams can have different compression levels, compression strategies, or window sizes since the `concatenate` function strips the zlib header of all but the first stream...

```py
from typing import Tuple
import zlib


def prepare(data: bytes) -> Tuple[int, bytes, int]:
    deflate = zlib.compressobj()
    result = deflate.compress(data)
    result += deflate.flush(zlib.Z_SYNC_FLUSH)
    return len(data), result, zlib.adler32(data)


def concatenate(*chunks: Tuple[int, bytes, int]) -> bytes:
    if not chunks:
        return b''
    _, result, final_checksum = chunks[0]
    for length, chunk, checksum in chunks[1:]:
        result += chunk[2:]  # strip the zlib header
        final_checksum = adler32_combine(final_checksum, checksum, length)
    result += b'\x03\x00'  # insert a final empty block
    result += final_checksum.to_bytes(4, byteorder='big')
    return result


def adler32_combine(adler1: int, adler2: int, length2: int) -> int:
    # Python implementation of adler32_combine
    # The orignal C implementation is Copyright (C) 1995-2011, 2016 Mark Adler
    # see https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/adler32.c#L143
    BASE = 65521
    WORD = 0xffff
    DWORD = 0xffffffff
    if adler1 < 0 or adler1 > DWORD:
        raise ValueError('adler1 must be between 0 and 2^32')
    if adler2 < 0 or adler2 > DWORD:
        raise ValueError('adler2 must be between 0 and 2^32')
    if length2 < 0:
        raise ValueError('length2 must not be negative')

    remainder = length2 % BASE
    sum1 = adler1 & WORD
    sum2 = (remainder * sum1) % BASE
    sum1 += (adler2 & WORD) + BASE - 1
    sum2 += ((adler1 >> 16) & WORD) + ((adler2 >> 16) & WORD) + BASE - remainder
    if sum1 >= BASE:
        sum1 -= BASE
    if sum1 >= BASE:
        sum1 -= BASE
    if sum2 >= (BASE << 1):
        sum2 -= (BASE << 1)
    if sum2 >= BASE:
        sum2 -= BASE

    return (sum1 | (sum2 << 16))
```

A quick example:

```py
hello = prepare(b'Hello World! ')
test = prepare(b'This is a test. ')
fox = prepare(b'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. ')
dawn = prepare(b'We ride at dawn! ')

# these all print what you would expect
print(zlib.decompress(concatenate(hello, test, fox, dawn)))
print(zlib.decompress(concatenate(dawn, fox, test, hello)))
print(zlib.decompress(concatenate(fox, hello, dawn, test)))
print(zlib.decompress(concatenate(test, dawn, hello, fox)))
```

Comment: Fantastic!  Used a similar version of this in Julia, and it is working really well.