# SYNC_FLUSH/FULL_FLUSH parameters in Java Deflater: relation to DEFLATE blocks?

Tags: java, zlib, deflate

In Java 7, [Deflater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html#FULL_FLUSH) has added support for some compression parameters (modes: `FULL_FLUSH`, `SYNC_FLUSH`). I guess that they correspond to Zlib similar [constants](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Constants) in the standard API (though this one has more modes).

My doubt is how those modes are related to the "blocks" of the DEFLATE stream (these blocks are compressed independently, except that a pointer inside a block might point to a raw substring of a previous block).

Does one (or both) of these modes implies that a flush terminates a (non final) DEFLATE block? Can the caller predict and/or suggest these block boundaries?

Specifically, I'd wish to tell the `Deflater` object the following: "I will feed you with `N` raw bytes in sections of predetermined length (`M`), and because I know that these sections are quite long and statistically different, and because I know that there is little to loose and something to gain in compressing them independently, I suggest you that compress them in separated DEFLATE blocks". Can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, both flushes terminate the current block after the provided input data.

`FULL_FLUSH` furthermore prevents the following blocks from using matching strings in the blocks before it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm wondering... considering that `FULL_FLUSH` is very similar to concatenating several zlib streams... is it easy/trivial to concatenate two ZLIB streams? I think it amounts to parse the blocks to change one final to nonfinal flag, plus recomputing the Adler [your] checksum... I'm right?

Comment: Already answered (by you) here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744692/concatenate-multiple-zlib-compressed-data-streams-into-a-single-stream-efficient , forget it.