# how to send multiple previously compressed files in a single http response to be consumed by a script?

Tags: javascript, java, http, httpresponse, http-compression

We have a scenario where we are sending multiple json files in a single response. These json files are stored as separate blobs in the backend (aerospike blobstore) and are fetched dynamically in response to a single request.

As long as we send these blobs uncompressed its working fine. i.e. we add a separator after each blob and use this separator to isolate each json blob something like this -

```
{
// first json here
}
-- JSONEND--blobid1

{
// second json here
}
-- JSONEND--blobid2
```

and so on.

As long as the blobs are uncompressed from the source i.e. blob store it works fine and we are able to isolate each json in javascript into a separate variable after parsing.

But our challenge is - these blobs are precompressed and saved into the blobstore for various reasons (performance / reduced diskspace ) and we want to simply send these compressed blobs in one response to the client. Scripts on client side use these blobs and parse them into separate json object trees.

Is this possible ? how ? We need to support only chrome and possibly firefox.

Comment: You never mentioned how are they compressed? Which method is used for compression?

Comment: Sure.. it's gzip and we have tested it for compliance with browser and it is

Comment: What you are trying is possible but not sure how you would do that at server level. See this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744692/concatenate-multiple-zlib-compressed-data-streams-into-a-single-stream-efficient

Comment: very interesting indeed .. although as a solution to my problem right now I would prefer something that uses http or websocket solutions and the blobs to be pre-compressed without any customization. I personally believe it should be possible to achieve it with a simpler option though yet to figure out.

Comment: Simplest option would be HTTP2 and sending multiple requests over same channel. But not sure if it works in your case or not

Comment: that's not an option unfortunately

Comment: I think it should work weather or not compressed, maybe the browser have trouble dealing gzip contents, then it's a browser bug. I suggest first check the gzip content through fiddler to make sure the data can be restored. then concatenate your responses in a more standard way like `{blobid1:{...},blobid2:{}..}` (or use array if has order)

Comment: @JoshLin the problem is not in gzip format .. the issue is we are trying to concatenate multiple precompressed DEFLATE blobs on server and retrieve these as separate ones on client. We would like browser decompression to do the job. One option we are looking at is using decompression through Javascript.

Comment: After some research I ruled out the JS decompression simply because its damn slow. We are now pretty convinced about doing it through websockets or http

Comment: Can you decompress the blobs, stick them together, and recompress it?

Answer (score 1):

if you using `Gzip` and you have a `nodejs` server

see here, how to use `gzjoin`

```
gzjoin.c
    join gzip files without recalculating the crc or recompressing
    - illustrates the use of the Z_BLOCK flush parameter for inflate()
    - illustrates the use of crc32_combine()
```

https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/master/deps/zlib/examples

Zlib documentation:
https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_zlib

Comment: Its not clear how we will retrieve different json blobs on client side. the answer would be kind of parsing the entire blob stream which I am not sure if its feasible. Any examples / clues as to how to retrieve the blobs on client side ?

Comment: examples here https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/master/deps/zlib/examples

Answer (score 0):

this is correct answer:

```
gzlog.c
gzlog.h
    efficiently and robustly maintain a message log file in gzip format
    - illustrates use of raw deflate, Z_PARTIAL_FLUSH, deflatePrime(),
      and deflateSetDictionary()
    - illustrates use of a gzip header extra field
```

OR

```
zpipe.c
    reads and writes zlib streams from stdin to stdout
    - illustrates the proper use of deflate() and inflate()
    - deeply commented in zlib_how.html (see above)
```

OR

```
zran.c
    index a zlib or gzip stream and randomly access it
    - illustrates the use of Z_BLOCK, inflatePrime(), and
      inflateSetDictionary() to provide random access
```