# how to join (concat) two deflated values without decompression/recompression

Tags: php, algorithm, compression, deflate

I have a lot of text files, i want to compress them to save disk space, then when I need them, concat them and send to a client. To save CPU cycles, I don't want to decompress/recompress data. Also client should be able to decompress data, and result should be joined/concated.

Here is what I did so far and it's result (code in PHP language):

```
$str1 = "Hello";
$str2 = "World";

$deflate1 = gzdeflate($str1);
$deflate2 = gzdeflate($str2);

$concat = substr($deflate1, 0, -2) . $deflate2;

$inflate = gzinflate($concat);
print($inflate);
```

Result:

```
HellnWorld
```

As you see, the last character of the first string is changed from `o` to `n`.

How can I fix this algorithm? (algorithms or c/php/go sample codes are ok).

Comment: It's [_techincally_ possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744692/concatenate-multiple-zlib-compressed-data-streams-into-a-single-stream-efficient) but implementing that in userland PHP code will likely be orders of magnitude slower than just re-encoding the whole stream.

Comment: This is most likely not going to work.  This is assuming that each returned value from deflation is aligned on a convenient boundary that just adding the two strings together will match up.  You could try and encode them and send them with some way of identifying the separate parts, then decode them as 2 rather than 1.

Comment: @Sammitch But that link includes the author of gzlib pointing to C implementations of the same.  If it is your PHP server on which you can install code, finding ways to use those implementations may be more straightforward, and should be much faster than the current approach.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just toss the compressed files into an uncompressed tar file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're trying to do with the output of `gzdeflate()` won't work. You cannot delete bytes from the end to attempt concatenation. You *can* simply concatenate gzip streams (without deleting anything), as produced by PHP's `gzencode()`, which are then valid gzip data. Though I am told that `gzdecode()` has a bug, and will not decode such a sequence of gzip members. (Someone should report the bug.)

You can use `deflate_init()` and `deflate_add()`, with appropriate flush options, to build up a compatible, complete deflate stream. For each individual stream, you would use `ZLIB_SYNC_FLUSH`, followed by `ZLIB_FINISH` to make a deflate stream that ends with a an empty, stored deflate block, which ends on a byte boundary, and then an empty fixed block marked as the last block. That final empty fixed block is two bytes. If it is deleted from the end, then you can concatenate another deflate stream after it. The last such piece concatenated should *not* have the last two bytes deleted, so that the whole thing is a properly terminated deflate stream.

When trying this, I found another bug. `deflate_add()` will not honor the `ZLIB_SYNC_FLUSH` request if the data string is empty. You can repeatedly call `deflate_add($def, '', ZLIB_SYNC_FLUSH);` all day long, and it will do nothing. You need to use `ZLIB_SYNC_FLUSH` on your last call of `deflate_add()` *with* some data. For example:

```php
$def = deflate_init(ZLIB_ENCODING_RAW);
$out = deflate_add($def, 'this ', ZLIB_NO_FLUSH);
$out = deflate_add($def, 'is ', ZLIB_NO_FLUSH);
$out .= deflate_add($def, 'a test.', ZLIB_SYNC_FLUSH);
$out .= deflate_add($def, '', ZLIB_FINISH);
```

(For some reason, I have never answered a question about PHP without discovering more bugs in PHP. I wonder why people use it.)

Edit by OP: Here is what is exactly needed:

```php
// first file
$def1 = deflate_init(ZLIB_ENCODING_RAW);
$file1 = deflate_add($def1, "1111111111", ZLIB_SYNC_FLUSH);

// second file, compress in two part
$def2 = deflate_init(ZLIB_ENCODING_RAW);
$file2 = deflate_add($def2, "22222", ZLIB_NO_FLUSH);
$file2 .= deflate_add($def2, "33333", ZLIB_SYNC_FLUSH);

// join on the fly
// $def3 = deflate_init(ZLIB_ENCODING_RAW);
// $joined = $file1 . $file2;
// $joined .= deflate_add($def3, "", ZLIB_FINISH);
// or simply :
$joined = $file1 . $file2 . "\03\00";

// decompress
$decompress = gzinflate($joined);
```

Comment: RFC1952(?) allows gzip concatenation. The problem is that gzdecode() can't decode them, although docs says it is RFC compliant (a bug maybe?)

Comment: Yep, that would be a bug. If it does not decode a sequence of gzip members, then it is not RFC 1952 compliant.

Comment: Thank you for editing your answer and adding details and codes. I just added another example that directly answers the question, just to save mine and others time in the future.

Comment: And... I mostly use php for testing, prototyping and learning new things, or for non-production codes to ease my daily tasks, I'm more comfortable with it for some reasons. And, I just noticed your name, glad you are here sir! 

Comment: I tried this @MarkAdler and I believe it works (java), but for some reason, with compression level 0, in Java, it does not. (not finishing any blocks and just concatenating those special bytes).

Comment: @user129393192 Ask a new question on stackoverflow.